# How to force a crash in FirebaseCrashlytics iOS newest upgrade?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

[image]

To force a crash in previus Crashlytics:

```swift
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

I am trying this, but the function doesn't exist:

```swift
Crashlytics.crashlytics().crash()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crash` method has been removed.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?hl=en-419#the_crash_and_throwexception_methods_are_removed

Answer (score 1):

Just put in a `fatalError()`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios&authuser=0

Also, so it recognizes the newest SDK add to your "Run Script" "shell" this

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}

${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```